# Angular2 get single data from firebase and card schema

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Hello guys I'm new with firebase and with ecommerce and I'm just trying to dummy app for listing ecommerce products.However, I couldn't make the idea of card.Then made a new table at firebase as Card and put the userId so that I was going to take data at buy page according to userId but couldn't take a single data.(able to take all list with `this.card = this.afdatabase.list('/card/') )`.

Here is my schema please advice me for a better schema.
[image]

I guess I found a solution like `list('/card/').foreach(d=>)`
but it will be so much time consuming for checking all data.
What is the solution for taking the products according to userId?

edit my addCard and getting data

```
card: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
addCard(item, amount) {
this.card.push(
  {
    productDetails: item,
    amount: amount,
    userId: this.userId
  }
);


this.card = this.afdatabase.list('/card/');
```

[image]

this returns when I console.log

```
 this.card= this.afdatabase.list('/card', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'userId',
    equalTo: this.userId
  }
});
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you could also show your service too

Comment: Sorry my bad , I did it. If you need more let me know please.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the data by `userid` you can do this

```
this.card = this.afdatabase.list('/card', { query : {
        orderByChild: 'userid',
        equalTo: this.userid
      });
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply but I tried your code and console.log the this.card  and it returned firebaseListObservable I will put the image at the post. How can I take the data there.Thank you

Comment: Hello I just made with orderbychild and foreach is it correct way or is there any better idea ?
console.log("card ", this.card.forEach(d=>{
          console.log("aaaa: ", d);
        }))

Comment: I actually don't see a reason why you need foreach. Is just using the orderbychild is not enough?

Comment: but i gave the result as a picture at post did you see it i wasnt able to take the data without foreach.

Comment: can you do a console log of this.card? How did you display it? did you subscribe to it or use an async pipe in your template?

Comment: Actually, I did with your way i just understood a bit late (: , i am using "foreach" for now getting the length of the this.card

Comment: it would be helpful if you could show more of your code. I don't think you need "foreach" just to get the count cause you are getting a list, you can do just .count

Comment: this.cart = this.afdatabase.list('/cart/', {
          query: {
            orderByChild: 'userId',
            equalTo: this.userId
          }
 });
this.card.forEach(item => {
        this.tempCart = this.tempCart.concat(item);
        this.cartLength = item.length;
  
 })
I m not able to take length of FirebaseListObservable (this.cart) so that i did foreach and got the item.length